# Scala for comprehension with Map iteration

Tags: scala, yield, flatmap, for-comprehension

I gone through a bunch of codes and tutorials and i still don’t understand how to iterate the Map through the for comprehension.

For example : I have a Map. Key as a string (student name) and the value as student details. I wants to iterate the student Map as each key and value. How can i achieve this through for comprehension.

Here’s the code i tried but i failed to understand

```
for {   
  studentMap <- studRepo.getAllStudent()// returns a map
  result1 <- performSomeOper(studentMap.key) // I’m not getting an option to access the key/value
  result2 <- performSomeOper(studentMap.value)
} yield performYieldOps(result1, result2)
```

What i’m doing wrong here ? Do i needs to keep the studentMap outside the for comprehension? Please feed me your input.

Answer (score 3):

```
  for {
    (key, value) <- studRepo.getAllStudent()
    res1 <- performSomeOper(key)
    res2 <- performSomeOper(value)
  } yield ...
```

You can map **key, value** from `Map`.

and `for comprehension` actual is equal to `flatMap`, so for the above equal to:

```
  m.flatMap {
    case (key, value) => ...
  }
```

Comment: Great. That's awesome. If i have the value as List<Student> how can i get that first item from that list ? Do i needs to do foreach or is there a way to access like value.get(0) ? BTW, you saved my day

Comment: `list.headOption` or `list.head`

Comment: I'm getting the compiler error since the Key is expected to be string but it's giving type of Any and it's giving series of error which all related to type mismatch.